# Is Set-StrictMode incompatible with parameter blocks?

Tags: powershell

I've got a simple script

```
Param([string] $myStringValue)
echo $myStringValue
```

And when I call it with `./test.ps1 -myStringValue steve`, it works just fine.

But if I add Set-StrictMode to the beginning:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
Param([string] $myStringValue)
echo $myStringValue
```

I get the following errors:

```
> ./test.ps1 -myStringValue steve
The variable '$myStringValue' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At D:\code\cadgraphics\test.ps1:2 char:20
+     Param([string] $myStringValue)
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (myStringValue:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined

The variable '$myStringValue' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At D:\code\cadgraphics\test.ps1:3 char:10
+     echo $myStringValue
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (myStringValue:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

I tried setting `$myStringValue` beforehand

```
$myStringValue = ''
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
Param([string] $myStringValue)
echo $myStringValue
```

but that just made it choke on the Param block:

```
Param : The term 'Param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\code\cadgraphics\test.ps1:3 char:5
+     Param([string] $myStringValue)
+     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Param:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you can mark the parameter as mandatory, or initialize it to something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `param()` needs to be first (or only preceded by certain special statements). Put `Set-StrictMode` after the `param()` block.

You can see this in ISE because the syntax highlighting will change `param()` from dark blue (statement) to blue (cmdlet/function/expression).